# timepicker with current date validation

Tags: javascript, html, date, time

I want a to add javascript to a time field so that it does not take current or previous time for the current date.. It should also not take 4 hours more than the current time for the current date... For eg : if date is 2018-03-03 and time is 13:00:00 then it should not take time less than 17:00:00 for the current date ..  the time format is hh:mm:ss. I am taking the date in another field in yyyy-mm-dd format.
Here is the code that I tried. Please tell me what can be changed.

```
function currtime()
var tm = document.getElementById("ptime");
var pd = document.getElementById("pdate");

var now =new date();
var select = new Date(now.getFullYear(),now.getMonth(),now.getDate());
var specific = new Date(pd);

if  ((specific == select) && (tm <= now)){
alert("incorrect time for today");
return false;
}

else {
return true;
}
```

Comment: "Please tell me what can be changed." is not a question.  What isn't working?  Be specific.

Comment: Where you have `tm <= now` you are comparing a Date to an HTML element (or null) which is unlikely to ever be true. You want to start with  `tm.value`, but further work is required.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) to create specified date in one line then you can compare dates using relational operators:

```
function currtime() {
    var tm = document.getElementById("ptime").value.split('-');
    var pd = document.getElementById("pdate").value;

    var specified = new Date(tm[0], tm[1] - 1, tm[2], ...tm.split(':'));
    var select = new Date();

    if (specified < select || specified > select.setHours(select.getHours() + 4)){
        alert("incorrect time for today");
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }   
}
```

Comment: @guijob the way you saw my problem was good but this code is displaying the alert for every time value entered..even if it is correct.. plus its working only if i write as document.getElementById("ptime").value; ... Please let me know what has to be done

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of issues with your code.

```
function currtime()
  var tm = document.getElementById("ptime");
  var pd = document.getElementById("pdate");
```

The value of *tm* and *pd* are HTML elements (or null). Guessing that they are HTML time and date inputs, you want to get their values:

```
  var tm = document.getElementById("ptime").value;
  var pd = document.getElementById("pdate").value;
```

Then there is:

```
var now =new date();
var select = new Date(now.getFullYear(),now.getMonth(),now.getDate());
```

If you want *select* to be a Date for the current date at 00:00:00, then it's simpler to get a Date and zero the time part:

```
var select = new Date();
select.setHours(0,0,0,0);
```

Anyway, you don't need to do that. Then there is:

```
var specific = new Date(pd);
```

Assuming that *pd* is an ISO 8601 format date like 2018-03-04, then it will be parsed as UTC so the time will be offset as for the host system offset. Likely you want it parsed as local. So you can either write a simple function to parse the value of *pd* as local, or build an ISO 8601 format date string for the local date and compare that.

But why not use the values from *tm* and *pd* to create a Date, then compare it to now and see if the time difference is more than 4 hours (or 14.4e6ms)? If you want it to be on the same date **and** within 4 hours, a bit more logic is required.

```js
function within4Hours() {
  // Get date and time values as array of parts
  var d = document.getElementById('pdate').value.split('-');
  var t = document.getElementById('ptime').value.split(':');
  // Create date from parts
  var date = new Date(d[0], d[1]-1, d[2], t[0], t[1]);

  // Return true if difference is < 4hrs, otherewise false 
  return Math.abs(date - Date.now()) <= 1.44e7;
}
```

```html
Date: <input type="date" id="pdate" value="2018-03-04"><br>
Time: <input type="time" id="ptime" value="10:23"><br>
<button onclick="console.log(within4Hours())">Within 4 hours of now?</button>
```

Note that this checks if the provided time is 4 hours either side of now. If you only want it in the future, adjust the test in the return statement.

Comment: plus time value should be in hh:mm:ss

Comment: @Sanjay—sorry, not a code writing service. I think there's plenty here for you to get what you want. Time inputs mostly only support hh:mm, but some also have ss (some don't support time or date). If you want to guarantee hh:mm:ss you'll need to use a text input with screen tip and validation.